# Append text in rich text box from inside of a while loop which performs continuous reading of TcpClient

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying to set up a program that is available to read incoming data packets from a TcpClient. The idea is to perform a continuous reading of data in a while loop and display it in the rich text box element. As an example I have been trying to set up my program like this (the reading part of tcp client is omitted to reduce code amount):

program.cs - main entry point:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Testing
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Class, where the while loop is set up:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Testing
{
    class Whiler
    {        
        public static void Stremer()
        {
            Thread Streamer = new Thread(OutPutFromWhile);
            Streamer.Start();
            OutPutFromWhile();
        }

        public static void OutPutFromWhile()
        {
            int i = 0;
            Form1 mybox = new Form1();
            // I want to display all i values from this while loop in the textbox
            while (true)
            {
                i++;
                mybox.richTextBox1.AppendText(i.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Whiler.Stremer();
        }
    }
}
```

Forms1.Designer.cs

```
namespace Testing
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 103);
            this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(659, 280);
            this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 29);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(658, 52);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        public System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can't access UI components directly from a thread other than the UI thread. Use [BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke).

Comment: You also have this: `Form1 mybox = new Form1();`. That's a new Form. Whatever you set in this **new** instance of Form1, won't be reflected in the existing one. Pass the current instance reference to your `Whiler` class in its contructor, and use this reference to update a control in the existing Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The UI thread is the only thread that may do UI actions!**
One of the problems that you will encounter, is that a non-UI thread will try to update the user interface. Only the UI-thread may do this.

In your case, consider using a `BackgroundWorker` to do the reading.

You could decide to create a class derived from `BackgroundWorker` to do your work. However, as your `BackgroundWorker` doesn't have a lot of functionality, it's just as easy to use the standard `BackGroundWorker` and its `DoWork` event.

Use your windows forms designer to add a BackgroundWorker. Change the properties in the properties window.

```
WorkerReportsProgress = true;
WorkerSupportsCancel = true;
```

React on events:

```
DoWork = DoBackGroundWork
ProgressChanged = ReportProgress
RunWorkerCompleted = ReportBackgroundWorkCompleted
```

Or alternatively use the constructor:

```
private readonly BackGroundWorker backgroundWorker;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker
    {
        WorkerReportsProgress = true,
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true,
    };

    // Subscribe to events:
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += this.DoBackGroundWork;
    backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += this.OnReportProgress;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += this.ReportBackgroundWorkCompleted;

    // make sure that the BackgroundWorker is properly disposed if this form is disposed:
    if (this.components == null) this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.components.Add(this.backgroundWorker);
}
```

**DoBackgroundWork** is the event function that does the Background work. The function is performed by the background worker. It is not the UI thread. Don't do anything on this form. Do what your background worker needs to do When it has some data that must be displayed call `ReportProgress`. Regularly check `CancellationPending` to see if it should stop working

```
private void DoBackGroundWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var backgroundWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    While(!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
    {
        // continue producing output
        var producedOutput = ...
        // report that new output is available:
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, producedOutput);
    }
}
```

The first parameter in ReportProgress is a number indicating the progress of this background thread. It can be used by the UI to fill a progress bar. As you don't know how long you will be producing data, you can't fill in a proper number.

**OnReportProgress** is called when the background worker reports progress
This function is executed by the UI thread. Feel free to do anything UI related

```
private void OnReportProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // you know the type that is reported as progress,
    // it is the type of the produced output
    string producedText = (string)e.UserState;
    this.AddToRichTextBox(producedText);
}
```

**ReportBackgroundWorkCompleted** is only needed if you need to do something if the background worker completes. It is executed by the UI thread

```
private void ReportBackgroundWorkCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // finished background working. Do some cleanup
    this.ShowBackgroundWorkerActive(false); // for example: hide ajax loader gif
}
```

**Use the background worker**:

```
void ShowBackGroundWorkerActive(bool active)
{
    // give user indication about active backgroundworker, for instance show ajax loader gif
    this.GifBackgroundWorkerActive.Visible = active;
}

bool IsBackGroundWorkerActive => this.GifBackgroundWorkerActive.Visible;

void StartBackgroundWorking()
{
     if (this.IsBackgroundWorkerActive) return; // already active

     // do some preparations:
     this.ShowBackgroundWorkerActive(true);

     // start the backgroundworker
     this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
void CancelBackgroundWorking()
{
    this.backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}
```

**Stop background working if the form is to be closed**

The only thing you'll have to do is make sure that your window isn't closed with an active background worker. Use event `OnFormClosing` for this.

```
bool formClosingRequested = false;
void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.BackGroundWorkerActive)
    {
        // can't close right now: need to stop the backgroundWorker first.
        // remember that we want to close the form:
        this.formClosingRequested = true;
        this.CancelBackgroundWorking();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    // else, no reason to cancel closing
}
```

When the background worker is completed, after a from close was requested, we'll have to close the form.

```
void ReportBackgroundWorkCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // finished background working. Do some cleanup
    this.ShowBackgroundWorkerActive(false);

    if (this.formClosingRequested)
    {
       // Close the form. This will lead to a FormClosingEvent
       // but this time the background worker won't be active
       this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I manged to do everything I wanted to by using your answer with a little tweak: I have added Thread.Sleep(SomeTime) in the DoWork function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

UI controls really need to be accessed from the UI thread only. This can be done using the winforms BeginInvoke method which will push the specified code onto the UI thread's queue. using your example code...

```
while (true)
{
    i++;
    mybox.BeginInvoke ((MethodInvoker) delegate
    {
        mybox.richTextBox1.AppendText(i.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    });
}
```

this will solve the access issue.

Note however that you can still hang up the UI thread by flooding it with BeginInvokes which this tight loop would probably do. I assume this is just an example though and the TCP data will come in much slower and less frequent. If not then you may need to rethink this and possibly batch it or only update after certain time intervals.